# Динамическое добавление значения в input text

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно динамически (id будут подставляться автоматически) при клике добавлять значения input в другой input. Как это сделать? Сейчас добавляет только первое значение.

- Значения при нажатии кнопок в поля заменяются.
- Одна кнопка add добавляет значение в name="add" и заменяется сама на другую кнопку del после нажатия, и наоборот, появившиеся кнопка del вместо add, добавляет то же значение (id, value) в другое поле name="del"
- Не трогая name="add" (взаимно)
- И наоборот постоянное переключение кнопок одна взаимен другой.

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>                 $(document).ready(function() {
>                   $("input[class^='locatio-']").on('click', function () {
>                      $("input[name=add]").val($("input[class^='location-']").val());
>                       });
>                   });
> </script>
> ```

```
<input type="text" name="add" value="" />
<input type="text" name="del" value="" /> 

<input type="text" class="location-1" value="1" />
<input type="button" class="add-1" value="add1" />
<input type="button" class="del-1" value="del1" />

<input type="text" class="location-2" value="2" />
<input type="button" class="add-2" value="add2" />
<input type="button" class="del-2" value="del2" />

<input type="text" class="location-3" value="3" />
<input type="button" class="add-3" value="add3" />
<input type="button" class="del-3" value="del3" />

<input type="text" class="location-4" value="4" />
<input type="button" class="add-4" value="add4" />
<input type="button" class="del-4" value="del4" />
```

Comment: А можно узнать, что из этого должно получиться в конечном итоге?) Как-то странно всё выглядит... это какая-то игра?

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME Вы почти все правильно сделали, просто новое поле для добавления результатов с дополнительной кнопки, и эти кнопки меняются одна на другую при клике, 3 jquery блока кода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

что-то такое вам надо?

```js
$(".add").click(function(){

   var append = $("#mode").prop('checked');
   var value = null;

   if(append){
      value =  $(this).siblings(".location").val();
   }
   else{   
       value = $(".location").map( function(){ 
                     return $(this).val(); 
                  }).get().toString();
   }
                  
  $("#favadd").val(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label><input type="checkbox" id="mode"/>Добавлять/заменять</label><br/>

<input type="text" id="favadd" value="" />

<div>
  <input type="text" name="location[]" class="location" value="1" />
  <button class="add">+</button>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="text" name="location[]" class="location" value="2" />
  <button class="add">+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Нужно подстановка по одному, заменять по каждому значению.

Comment: @php дописал чутка

Comment: Можно сразу с галочкой, почему у меня не работает в html файле?

Comment: @php jquery мб не подключен?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='button']").on('click', function () {
    // Надо получить инпут связанный с кнопкой
    const location = $(this).attr('class');
    const $input = $(`input[type='text'].${location}`);
    $("input[name=add]").val($input.val());
  });
});
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 150px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="add" value="" />
<hr>
<input type="text" class="location-1" value="1" />
<input type="button" class="location-1" value="1" />
<input type="text" class="location-2" value="2" />
<input type="button" class="location-2" value="2" />
<input type="text" class="location-3" value="3" />
<input type="button" class="location-3" value="3" />
<input type="text" class="location-4" value="4" />
<input type="button" class="location-4" value="4" />
```